# How to work with MapEntry in Java?

Tags: java

First of all I have a class that extends AbstractMap.

```
public class ShowMap <K, V> extends AbstractMap <K, V>
```

Class has two containers of type List:

```
private List <K> keys = new ArrayList <K> ();
private List <V> values = new ArrayList <V> ();
```

Class has a several methos as well.
The method V put take an argument like a key and put it into List keys:

```
public V put (K key, V value){
    V oldValue = this.get(key);
    if (!keys.contains(key)){
        keys.add(key);
        values.add(value);
    }
    else{
        values.set(keys.indexOf(key), value);
    }

    return oldValue;
}
```

The method V get returns a value from List values, otherwise the method teturn null:

```
public V get (Object obje){
    if (!keys.contains(obje))
        return null;
    return values.get(keys.indexOf(obje));
}
```

The following method forms a set of MapEntry, but it doesn't work:

```
public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {

    Set <Map.Entry<K, V>> sets = new HashSet <Map.Entry<K, V>> ();
    Iterator<K> ki = keys.iterator();
     Iterator<V> vi = values.iterator();

     while (ki.hasNext()){
        sets.add(new MapEntry <K, V> (ki.next(), vi.next())); // This line should to work, however It doesn't work...
     }
    return sets;
}
```

The main method of course:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    ShowMap <String, String> SM = new ShowMap <String, String> ();
    SM.putAll(Countries.FMap.capitals(10));
    System.out.println(SM);
    System.out.println(SM.get("Moscow"));
    System.out.println(SM.entrySet());
}
```

Thank a lot:)

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"?  What's the error or the incorrect behaviour?

Comment: `MapEntry` isn't a class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) not `MapEntry`.  You also probably specifically want [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)

Comment: Thank you! MapEntry is a class that implements Map.Entry <>.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set <Map.Entry<K, V>> sets = new HashSet <Map.Entry<K, V>> ();
        Iterator<K> ki = keys.iterator();
         Iterator<V> vi = values.iterator();

         while (ki.hasNext()){
            sets.add(new MapEntry <K, V> (ki.next(), vi.next())); // This line should to work, however It doesn't work...
         }
        return sets;
    }
```

Here you are returning a set of Map.Entry and not of MapEntry. Moreover, MapEntry is not a class. Please update the code.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.Entry<K,V>` is an interface. You can create a named class for its instantiation, or use an anonymous class, like this:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> sets = new HashSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> ();
    Iterator<K> ki = keys.iterator();
    Iterator<V> vi = values.iterator();
    while (ki.hasNext()){
        final K key = ki.next();
        final V val = vi.next();
        sets.add(new Map.Entry<K,V>() {
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (!(obj is Map.Entry)) return false;
                Map.Entry other = (Map.Entry)obj;
                return key.equals(other.getKey()) && val.equals(other.getValue());
            }
            public int hashCode() {
                return 31*key.hashCode()+val.hashCode();
            }
            public K getKey() { return key; }
            public V getValue() { return val; }
            public void setValue(V v) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        });
    }
    return sets;
}
```

The anonymous class provides a simple implementation of the interface. This is suitable only if you plan to use your `Map.Entry` only inside a single method. Otherwise you would be better off with a named class that has similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! MapEntry is a class that implements Map.Entry <?, ?>.